# Matrix conversion involving first and second largest values row-wise

Tags: r

I have a matrix `mat`:

```
#sample data
set.seed(123)
mat <- t(sapply(1:5, function(x) round(sample(10:30, 6))))

mat
16   25   17   29   27   10
21   27   20   18   26   17
24   21   11   26   14   10
16   29   26   22   20   25
23   24   20   28   14   12
```

I want to replace each row with that row's maximum (this is easy), but I also want to replace the maximum row's value with that row's second largest value (this is less easy). My desired output would be:

```
res
29   29   29   27   29   29
27   26   27   27   27   27 
26   26   26   24   26   26
29   26   29   29   29   29
28   28   28   24   28   28
```

For example, 29 is the largest value in row 1 and it occurs in position 4; the second largest value is 27.  So I want a row of 29s with a 27 in position 4. And then of course to do this for all rows.

My attempt:

```
# the easy part
res <- matrix(apply(mat, 1, max), nrow=nrow(mat), ncol=ncol(mat))

# my attempt at the hard part
to_replace <- apply(mat, 1, which.max)
whos_2nd <- apply(mat, 1, function(x) which(order(x, decreasing = TRUE) == 2))

res[cbind(1:nrow(mat), to_replace)] <- mat[cbind(1:nrow(mat), whos_2nd)]
```

Something is wrong with the `apply` in the "whos_2nd" line, and I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm also very open to a more efficient solution, as I'm dealing with larger matrices, and many of them.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another base R possibility using `apply` with `ifelse`

```
t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) ifelse(x == max(x), sort(unique(x), decr = T)[2], max(x))))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]   29   29   29   27   29   29
#[2,]   27   26   27   27   27   27
#[3,]   26   26   26   24   26   26
#[4,]   29   26   29   29   29   29
#[5,]   28   28   28   24   28   28
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in one call to `apply`:

```
t(apply(mat, MAR = 1, function(x){
  max_index <- which.max(x)
  max_value <- max(x)
  sec_value <- sort(unique(x), decreasing = TRUE)[2]
  x <- replace(x, TRUE, max_value)
  x[max_index] <- sec_value
  x
}))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]   29   29   29   27   29   29
# [2,]   27   26   27   27   27   27
# [3,]   26   26   26   24   26   26
# [4,]   29   26   29   29   29   29
# [5,]   28   28   28   24   28   28
```